# Servlets: doPost and doGet simple inquiry

Tags: servlets

```
public class CornelltaxiServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    //resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    //resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
}
```

}

From my understanding of doGet and doPost, it shouldn't matter where I put the "Hello, world" message. However, when I try to print it using the doPost method, it does not work. Could anyone explain this for me?

Also, from

```
void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Preprocess request: we actually don't need to do any business stuff, so just display JSP.
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

what does this do?

Comment: How are you sending data? You need to submit a form for a doPost to be hit

Answer (score 2):

The `doGet()` method is called when HTTP GET is requested (e.g. when you type your servlets' URL in the browser). Then `Hello, world` will appear in the browser.

`doPost()` on the other hand will be used on HTTP POST. You need for example:

```
<form method="POST" action="/your/servlet"
```

When you submit such a form, you should see "Hello, world" (that is - when you uncomment it) in the browser as well.

As for your second question:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

This will forward request processing to `hello.jsp`. Basically, the contents of that file will be rendered instead of your `Hello, world`. Sending both content using `resp.getWriter()` and forwarding is a mistake. Pick one.